# My 2012 Sonata having hard start problem

Tags: starting, hyundai, sonata

Pls my Hyundai sonata 2012 is giving me hard start issue sometimes it starts but as soon as I off the engine it will take another 30mins to start again. Right now the car is not coming on sometimes I will need to put my leg on the accelerator before it can start. I spoke to a rewire he said the attached picture is the cause of the issue that the device is not pushing fuel to the engine as required pls advise further

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I believe what is pictured is the high pressure fuel pump.

Answer (score 0):

[image]There appears to be a missing connection in your snapshot.

Answer (score -1):

Check the spark plugs first to see if it's functioning well then later get the fuel pump changed, that's if the spark plugs are ohk.
Finally make sure there is enough fuel.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more prudent to do the easiest things first, like check the fuel?